# how to set root path for resources in web.xml

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have two servlet mappings in my web.xml   I want to set a root path for the resources that I will be referencing for the below servlet. My goal is to not have to put the entire path in my JSP's.

Example:  instead of having to put a image path of (resources/admin/images) i would like to be able to put (/images)

File structure is as follows:

```
 |_ admin
    |_index.jsp
    |_resources
         |_images
         |_views
              |_dashboard.jsp (file in which I want to use the scoped file paths)
```

I have a root scope that is the base for my site(localhost.com)  I want to have another scope that is at the admin level I am trying to define (localhost.com/admin).

I tried searching but am unsure what to add to my servlet mapping.   Below is my web.xml

```xml
<display-name>cr</display-name>
<description>cr</description>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
        classpath:spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/spring-controllers.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/resources/admin/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: You should improve your question with more details. For example, where is the second servlet mapping? And add java tag so more people will see your question.

Comment: @DiogoSantana I added the whole web.xml.

Comment: "My goal is to not have to put the entire path in my JSP's": which entire path? What do you mean? What is your question actually?

Comment: @DiogoSantana I added some clarification.

Comment: You want to do that because of admin only access to these resources?

Comment: @DiogoSantana, only because I do not want the full file path exposed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don`t want the full file path exposed, put the jsp files inside the WEB-INF folder. Although you can't access directly the file inside WEB-INF folder, you can forward the request to it.

THe forward should be like this:

```
RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/admin/index.jsp");
view.forward(req, resp);
```